# Mobile site header arrow no longer functional on Windows Phone 7

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, windows-phone

As of yesterday I started noticing that the arrow on the mobile site's header isn't functional (click-able / touchable) as it once was. To clarify, the entire site renders fine, but the top portion where the StackOverflow logo appears with the arrow is no longer a link. Previously I was able to touch that arrow and it would reveal my rep and whatever else it typically displays. Now the arrow does nothing when pressed. I received a comment from a user and the arrow changed to a red "1" to indicate that, but that wasn't responsive when pressed either.

I'm using a WP7 and I am logged in. I've tried clearing my browser history just in case but that didn't help.

Has the mobile site changed or is this a legitimate bug?

Comment: Is there a Javascript error message at the bottom of the page? I had this in Chrome and Opera on my android, installing Firefox fixed it.

Comment: @shanethehat no JavaScript error at the bottom. I've never seen a Javascript error on my mobile browsers so either I've been lucky or they were suppressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed with the next code deploy.

Irony of ironies, some code that works around an IE bug on the desktop site in fact caused issues for IE on the mobile one.